# Hook into WordPress custom post type and change the row background color

Tags: php, wordpress

So I need some help and I can't seem to figure this out, but in the backend of WordPress I have a custom post type called "wp_events".

In there, I have "Scheduled", "Draft" and "Published" posts.

So let's take for example this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2LUd.png)

If the post is "Scheduled", I would like to have the whole row as a lightgreen background color.

I tried the following code:

```
// Add custom column CSS on wp_events admin 
function wp_events_custom_css($column) {

  // Only target status column
  if( $column == 'status') {

    echo '<style>
       .status-scheduled {
         background: lightgreen!important;
       }
    </style>';

  }

}

// Hook into column rendering
add_action('manage_wp_events_posts_custom_column', 'wp_events_custom_css', 10, 2);
```

But I am unable to target it properly, so I am looking to see if someone might be able to assist me or know an easier way.

I tried the above code and was expecting the row to turn a lightgreen color.

Comment: I haven’t checked, but maybe there is a class already implemented for scheduled posts. Else, you can use javascript to check all rows and color them when they contain the word ‘Scheduled’.

Comment: The last option would of course only be available in English versions of the backend.